# Rulings on developable surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry

How are rulings/ generators defined between definable and connectable points on a smooth arbitrary 3D parameterized curve:

$$ \{ x(t), y(t),z(t) \}?$$

forming a zero Gaussian curvature $K$ surface ?

$H=0 $ surfaces have minimal area. What is minimum for $K=0 ?$ Should the rulings be necessarily straight?

How are cone/cylinder /developable helicoid parts distinguished?

I have rough-sketched an easy example of the Viviani window where the straight rulings are conveniently taken parallel to y-axis using symmetry which appears to be one possibility for flat surface $K=0$.

[image]

Another example is $\{ \sin  2 t, \cos  3 t \cos t, \sin   4 t \}$ whose rulings are to be found.

[image]

Comment: Rulings are always lines, hence straight. Helicoids are ruled but far from developable.

Comment: OK, There are developable helicoids like what is depicted on DJ Struik's DG textbook.